# Как вставить у себя на сайте боковую закладку под названием , к примеру, "Online-консультант"?

Tags: веб-программирование

Если кто-то из мастеров владеет таким HTML-кодом или знает Интернет-ресурс, где можно
сгенерировать код такой закладки, поделитесь, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Я для сайта использовал решение mibew. Очень удобно и быстро. Весьма рекомендую.

Comment: Именно такая закладка мне и нужна.
Но поскольку я начинающий VEB-дизайнер сайта, то не знаю, что такое "mibew". Могли бы Вы написать код закладки?

Comment: [Посмотрите здесь](http://mibew.org/ru/demo.php) - ссылки на код тоже присутствуют. Я бы посоветовал почитать справку о принципах работы подобных систем.